# How to use Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable with named key in data?

Tags: powershell

I know how to use `-FilterXPath` and `-FilterXml`, but can't figure out how to use `-FilterHashTable` with the `Data` key and a named key, (e.g. **param2** key in EventData)

```
<EventData>
  <Data Name="param1">WMI Performance Adapter</Data> 
  <Data Name="param2">running</Data> 
</EventData>
```

**Example FilterXpath**

```
Get-WinEvent -LogName "System" -FilterXPath "*[System[EventID=7036] and EventData[Data[@Name='param2']='running']]"
```

**Example FilterXml**

```
$filter = @"
<QueryList>
    <Query Id='0' Path='System'>
        <Select Path='System'>*[System[(EventID=7036)]] and  *[EventData[Data[@Name='param2']='running']]</Select>
    </Query>
</QueryList>
"@

Get-WinEvent -FilterXml $filter
```

**Trying with FilterHashtable**

```
$filter = @{
    Id = 7036
    LogName = "Microsoft-SMA/Operational"
    Data    = "[EventData[Data[@Name='param2']='running']]"
}

Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable $filter
```

I am also aware that they added named key support in PS6

Answer (score 0):

In powershell 5.1, it can only be "data =", less specific but it still works:

```
get-winevent @{id = 7036; logname = 'system'; data = 'running'}
```

Powershell 7, "param2 =":

```
get-winevent @{id = 7036; logname = 'system'; param2 = 'running'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use -FilterHashtable, the parameter is straight up broken and sometime returns no data even when there are events. Example:

This returns no events

```
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{ProviderName="Microsoft-Windows-Kerberos-Key-Distribution-Center"}
```

This does return the events correctly

```
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{LogName='System'} | where {$_.ProviderName -eq "Microsoft-Windows-Kerberos-Key-Distribution-Center"}
```

With some providers, even though you spelled them correctly, the command claims that no events where found. Therefore I highly recommend to stick with -FilterXml, this parameter works reliably. The way I do it, I edit my query in the event viewer UI to confirm that I get the results I expect, then copy the Xml of the filter in my Powershell script.

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on there.  Every providername in my system log works for me.